# R code- ARIMA(2,0,2) state space model

Tags: r, arima, state-space-models

Does anyone know how to write the command in R to compute state space model of an ARIMA(2,0,2)?

Comment: Is what you want the state space representation of an ARIMA(2,0,2) model?

Answer (score 2):

Do something like

```
makeARIMA(phi=c(.8,.1),theta=c(.2,.5),Delta=0)
```

Comment: You wanted to edit "model" into "representation", but that is not obvious. I suggest asking the OP what he really meant. But +1 for a useful function.